# How does Tezos Checker work?

Tags: ligo

I am looking at [Tezos Checker](https://github.com/tezos-checker/segmented-cfmm) and wondering if there is a visualization of the process flow how it works? Specifically something like this for example? [image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a github issue on that project to ask questions regarding its usage.